# String Size Function not working

Tags: c++, string, function, size

My compiler is complaining that "Expression is not assignable" for the line of code handling the str.size function. I can't tell what I have wrong. Can someone help ? I'm passing a string into a function and trying to get the length of it.

```
   int ValueString::value(string str)const
   {
        int length;
        str.size() = length;
        return length;

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

[`str.size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) returns an R-value, which cannot be assigned to.

`length` is an L-value and *can* be assigned to.

You mean:

```
int ValueString::value(const string& str)const
{
    int length;
    length = str.size();
    return length;
}
```

This could, of course, be simplified to:

```
int ValueString::value(const string& str) const
{
    return str.size();
}
```

It could be simplified even further than that, perhaps...

Answer (score 3):

The compiler message says it all.  You can't assign to the result of the function call `size()`.  I think you probably mean `int length = str.size()`.